# How to set NuGet environment variable NUGET_CERT_REVOCATION_MODE` to false on appcenter.ms

Tags: configuration, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-app-center

I am working on `Xamarin.Forms` app that is using a private NuGet feed.

For iOS building, I use `appcenter.ms` that is recommended by Microsoft. I have set up the NuGet restore step via API key by adding `Nuget.config` next to `.sln` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="DevOps" value="https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
<apikeys>
    <add key="https://xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json" value="%encrypted_api_key%" />
</apikeys>
</configuration>
```

However, nuget restore on `appcenter.ms` takes so long that build times-out after 30 minutes.

I [suspect that](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/devops-build-pipeline-nuget-restore-very-slow-on-s/632309) issue is the [Revocation check mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3028)

[I would need to set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-environment-variables) the `NUGET_CERT_REVOCATION_MODE` to false.

**How to set NuGet environment variable `NUGET_CERT_REVOCATION_MODE` to false on `appcenter.ms`? or disable it some other way?**